# Visual Studio: Create Add-In That Creates Partial Class in C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, add-in

I'd like to have an Add-In in Visual Studio 2008 that will auto-generate some code as a partial class in C# for an existing class but I don't know where to start.

Any ideas or best practices would be greatly appreciated.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

What exactly do you want your addin to do with the existing class to generate this?

You can do similar things using the [Text Template Transformation Toolkit (T4)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb126445.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You can create an [item template](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tsyyf0yh.aspx) to accomplish this.